# Make button to fill whole width in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing the following logging component in React:

[image]

I want all the buttons to have the same width and I want them to fill the whole width available.

This is my code:

```
export default function Login (props: any) {
  return(
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        '& > :not(style)': {
          m: 1,
          width: 400,
          height: 500,
        },
      }}
    >
      <Paper elevation={10}>
        <div style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
          LOGIN
        </div>
        <div style={{paddingTop: 40}}>
          <form>
            <div style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
              <FormControl variant="standard">
                <InputLabel htmlFor="email">
                  Email
                </InputLabel>
                <Input
                  id="email"
                  startAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <PersonIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  }
                />
              </FormControl>
            </div>
            <div style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
              <FormControl variant="standard">
                <InputLabel htmlFor="password">
                  Password
                </InputLabel>
                <Input
                  id="password"
                  startAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <KeyIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  }
                />
              </FormControl>
            </div>
            <div style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
              <Button variant="contained">Accept</Button>
            </div>
            <div style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
              <Button variant="contained" endIcon={<GoogleIcon />}>
                Login with Google
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div style={{paddingTop: 30}}>
              <Button variant="contained" >
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
          </div>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a button take full width of container, you can set `fullWidth` prop to true in `Button` component. For more information you can refer [MUI Button API](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/#props).

**Working demo**: [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/switchlabels-material-demo-forked-gjvu10?file=/demo.js:462-2541)

**Like this:-**

```js
<Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        flexWrap: "wrap",
        padding: "20px 40px",
        "& > :not(style)": {
          m: 1,
          width: 400,
          height: 500
        }
      }}
    >
      <Paper
        elevation={10}
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          justifyContent: "center",
          flexDirection: "column"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ paddingTop: 30, textAlign: "center" }}>LOGIN</div>
        <div
          style={{ paddingTop: 40, display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}
        >
          <form>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
              <FormControl variant="standard">
                <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
                <Input
                  id="email"
                  startAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <PersonIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  }
                />
              </FormControl>
            </div>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
              <FormControl variant="standard">
                <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
                <Input
                  id="password"
                  startAdornment={
                    <InputAdornment position="start">
                      <KeyIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  }
                />
              </FormControl>
            </div>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
              <Button variant="contained" fullWidth>
                Accept
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
              <Button variant="contained" endIcon={<GoogleIcon />} fullWidth>
                Login with Google
              </Button>
            </div>
            <div style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
              <Button variant="contained" fullWidth>
                Cancel
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add full width to 100.

you can add it with a styled component, or inline in sx prop: {width:1}

in sx prop width 1 will be converted to 100% width

see the mui sizing page [here](https://mui.com/system/sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

Set attribute of each button: `style={{paddingTop: 30, width: "100%"}}`